# Custom Gstreamer plugin cannot be registered on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost, plugins, gstreamer

I am writing plugin for C++ that uses boost shared memory as source.
I am using Visual Studio 2022 and Windows 11 as environment. I used gstplugin.c gstplugin.h files from official gstreamer repository. My .dll compiles properly so I copied .dll and .pdb to lib\gstreamer-1.0. When I am using `gst-inspect-1.0 shared_memory_source` command I cannot see my plugin.

I tried to debug it with --gst-debug-level=4 but there is no information about my plugin.
I tried some tinkering with environment variable GST_PLUGIN_PATH but it didn't help. I even deleted registry.x86_64-msvc.bin to force plugin discovery.
Here is my code responsible for my plugin registration:

```
#ifndef PACKAGE
#define PACKAGE "shared_memory_source"
#endif
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
#define GST_LICENSE "LGPL"
#define GST_PACKAGE_NAME "shared_memory_source"
#define GST_PACKAGE_ORIGIN "https://XDDDDSDSA.pl/"

// gstreamer looks for this structure to register plugins
GST_PLUGIN_DEFINE (GST_VERSION_MAJOR,
    GST_VERSION_MINOR,
    plugin,
    "shared_memory_source",
    plugin_init,
    PACKAGE_VERSION, GST_LICENSE, GST_PACKAGE_NAME, GST_PACKAGE_ORIGIN)
```

I suspected that it may be issue with boost library linking:
[VS2022 linker settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6buk.png)

I want to know what am I missing and how to find future issues myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. It was typical rookie mistake. Name of the plugin is third argument that should be filled without quotes.

```
GST_PLUGIN_DEFINE (
GST_VERSION_MAJOR,
GST_VERSION_MINOR,
shared_memory_source,
"description",
plugin_init,
PACKAGE_VERSION, GST_LICENSE, GST_PACKAGE_NAME, GST_PACKAGE_ORIGIN)
```

Definition GST_PLUGIN_DEFINE provides macro for wrapping name as string G_STRINGIFY(name) in my case G_STRINGIFY(shared_memory_source) which will look something like "shared_memory_source"